# Which storage structure is the best?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I have a table -

```
CREATE TABLE `DBMSProject`.`ShoppingCart` (
  `Customer_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Seller_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Product_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Quantity` INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`Customer_ID`,`Seller_ID`,`Product_ID`));
```

This table has a lot more insert operations and delete operations than update operations..
Which storage structure is most suited in decreasing overall operation and access time ? I'm not sure between Hash Structure and B+ Tree structure and ISAM. PS - The number or records is in an order of 10 Million

Comment: The fact that you described a SQL DDL indicates to me you're already decided the storage structure is database (mysql)

Comment: Physical storage - which way is better ?. I know MySQL uses BTREE by default..But if I could change, which would be better is my question

Comment: MyISAM only supports BTREE and FULLTEXT indexes. It doesn't support HASH indexes.

Comment: I know that it doesnt... Its just a hypothetical scenario where I could.. If I could choose, which one would be better ?

Answer (score 0):

For a shopping cart, data integrity is more important than raw speed.

MyISAM doesn't support ACID transactions, and it doesn't enforce foreign keys constraints. With all those ID numbers you're showing, I wouldn't proceed with an engine that doesn't enforce foreign key constraints.

In general, I favor testing over speculation. You can build tables, load them with 10 million rows of random(ish) data, index them several different ways, and run timing tests with representative SQL statements in just a couple of hours. Use similar hardware, if possible.

And when it comes to indexes, you can drop them and add them without having to rewrite any application code. If you can't be bothered to test, just pick one. Later, if you have a performance problem that `explain` suggests might be related to the index, drop it and create a different one. (After you do this a couple of times, you'll probably discover that you *can* spare the time to test.)